# Windows hangs during (or after) execution of Java code generating many images

Tags: java, windows, swing, file-io, graphics

I am developing a code which sometimes has to generate a lot of images. The program works perfectly fine when I have relatively small number of images to generate, however when I have to generate tens of thousands of images something strange could happen.

At some random point Windows appears to hung during execution of the code for up to few minutes. Task manager claims that Java application uses 0% of processor at that time. In fact every application that tries to use a resource from hard drive hangs, but applications that are already opened and don't require access to the hard drive seems to work.

What is more strange this behavior could happen even few seconds/minutes after my program is finished. But sometimes it doesn't happen at all.

Here is the simplified example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            String dirName = "tmp/" + i + "/";
            File dir = new File(dirName);
            dir.mkdirs();
            //put only 200 file into one directory
            for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
                drawImage(dirName, j);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void drawImage(String dirName, int j) 
                             throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = bi.createGraphics();

    //draw something on the image
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        graphics.drawLine(k, 0, k*2, 512);
    BufferedImage tmpBI=new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D tmpGraphics = tmpBI.createGraphics();
    tmpGraphics.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, 512, 512, 0, 0, 512, 512, null);

    //write image to png
    FileOutputStream fos;
    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(dirName + "img" + j + ".PNG"));
    ImageIO.write(tmpBI, "PNG", fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

My first guess is that there are some problems with file handlers in OS or that my Java code improperly handles files.

The second guess is that garbage collector does some magic things that I don't understand.

But to be honest I have no idea how to find out what the real problem is and how to fix it.

I run the code on Windows 7 64bit and jdk1.7 64-bit with NTFS file system.

---

**UPDATE**

Few responses proposed some workarounds. I tested all of them with the same effect:

- change the output directory to USB memory stick
- additional thread for computations
- single ZIP file as the [output stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) for all files

The last try suprised me. I expected that in this case it wouldn't hang. So, I performed another test and instead of writing to file I used [`NullOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullOutputStream.html). The result was the same...

My conclusion: either there is something wrong in swing library (very unprobable) or maybe there is something wrong with my computer/OS. I will check it on other computers/OS. If the problem persists I will get back to it.

Comment: I Have absolutely no idea why you have to create thousands of 512x512 images. But, I think this might be a caching issue, maybe windows or java caches up the images that couldn't be written yet because of HD speed and somewhat that cache overflows. Try running that function saving into a USB flash drive or something see if you get any better results. Now, you should expect your program to freeze since you're processing LOTS of information in the gui thread, you may want to create a backgroud thread and track progress with a progress bar.

Comment: Also, other programs will naturally hang when trying to write into the hard disk during an operation of n-illions of bytes are already being written, they will have to 'wait in the line' to write their data.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2) An old trick for creating many files is to create one Zip file (with no compression) and write the many files into that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Can you tell me what is wrong with my example code? Before posting it, I run it several times to confirm that my Windows hangs with it... Creating ZIP file could help. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: *"Can you tell me what is wrong with my example code? Before posting it, I run it.."*  It is not about what *you* can do with the *complete code*, it is about what *people trying to help* you can do with *uncompilable code snippets*.  We cannot compile that, we cannot run it, so it is not an example of anything, from our perspective.

Comment: But, tell me what is missing? Except of imports I put everything that is required to compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you write access some kernell functions.

The open and close functions for OutputStream are partially done in native, so is createGraphics().

When accessing native functions, keep in mind that they will have their own synchronization implemented.

I believe you are in the scenario where the quantity of information sent to the native thread comes at a much higher pace then the native thread writes to disk (when you think about it, RAM memory access is way quicker then HDD memory).

Even if your Java machine quits, the "tasks" were already given to the native thread to write.
That's probably why all HDD operations are getting hanged.

Try adding a Thread Sleep to your thread in order to put the Java thread in a lower priority and see if this helps.

As a general rule of thumb, file creation is a very expensive operation.20000 files is hard to even be listed in a folder :).

Comment: I thought that it could have something to do with native methods. I will try adding Thread.sleep(1), but what would be more interesting is how to force Java to wait for OS? I don't mind if my program take more time, I just don't want to experience this hanging behaviour. Shouldn't this also happen when I copy 20k files? At that point nothing strange happens. I know that file creation is expensive, but I generate them only once and use on the web-server as a static data. I know the problem with listing etc. - this is why I divided them into separate, small folders.

Comment: I tried Thread.sleep, but OS still hangs, I will try to find a way to wait for OS I/O operations, but I'm not sure if it's possible (I can probably make it for Windows by hardocidng some stuff, but it should also behave in the same way under Linux).

Comment: Try Thread.sleep(100) :). The time to write to HDD is quite big. There are some tips and tricks that can help you with your problem, things like running on UI thread (eventhou you don't need any UI) or attempting to open an input stream from your previous created file will force synchronize your thread. Even println will end up syncing your program.

Comment: Regarding your comment that it should behave the same way under Linux : very wrong. Linux uses the ext file system, which caches writes to disk then dumps them all at once, while NTFS dumps directly to HDD.

Comment: I tried, sleep(1000) with the same results. For debug reasons I have plenty of println and log4j.debug functions (with file and console appender) and it doesn't help. Linux could use many underlying FS (ext is one of them) and I don't want to do the code OS/FS specific.

Comment: Ok... then try something very ugly , that might work. Make a native function that writes to a file a byte array, then create a jni bridge, and try to write using that native function instead of the Java Stream class. Use fprintf , not fstream (I remember someone telling me in the early days to avoid streams in C whenever possible). Try this for debug purposes. If your problem is solved, you will know that is indeed a native implementation problem,and you found a work around .

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did some additional test (and updated my initial post). I don't think anymore that it's related with IO operations.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that you should invoke the drawings on the UI thread, because you make use of awt.Graphics and BufferedImage. These are UI specific components and you always want to make UI operations on the UI thread.

Try somethig like:

```
 EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // do your graphics related operations here
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The part of the code that I presented above has nothing to do with user interface (I don't display them). The aim is to pre-generate set of files that will be used later on in a different part of a system.

Answer (score 0):

Try going multithreaded, so you don't use up your main thread. I guess this code is originally ran in a swing form other than console, if you do massive operations on the main thread the program won't redraw until the operation is over.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Thread operation = new Thread(new Runnable(ThreadOperation));
     operation.start();
}

public static void ThreadOperation() {
    try {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            String dirName = "tmp/" + i + "/";
            File dir = new File(dirName);
            dir.mkdirs();
            //put only 200 file into one directory
            for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
                drawImage(dirName, j);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also you may track the progress with a taskbar with a little more coding.

Now, you should really expect other programs to hang while your program saves a massive amount of data into the disk, since hard disks aren't as fast as your processor can be. Unless (or even if) you have an SSD HD you will have this issue.

Other programs hanging while your process writes your data, only means they're trying to write data into the disk using their main thread and won't redraw until they finish writing their data, then windows thinks: Wait this guy isn't redrawing... must be dead.

PS: This code might be wrong somewhere, i've been coding way too much in c# lately.

Comment: It's not the problem of GUI (I can handle with that), my problem is that Windows hangs. For instance when it starts hanging, I cannot even refresh the content of directory in Explorer. However, when you heavily use your HDD (by copying multiple files) it never occurs. After creation of the files I copy/zip/unzip/remove them from time to time and it never hangs OS. I tried changing HDD to USB stick, with the same effect